# Problema com macro

Tags: c, macro

Estou tentando resolver o seguinte exercicio:

> Escreva um programa que defina e use a macro PRINTARRAY para imprimir
>   um array de inteiros. A macro deverá receber o array e o numero de
>   elementos no array como argumento

O que fiz ate agora:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN_VETOR 4
#define PRINTARRAY(vetor,length)while(length > 0){ \
                         printf("%d",vetor[length]);\
                         length--;                 \
                       }                           \

int main(void)
{
    int vetor[] = {1,2,3,4};
    PRINTARRAY(vetor,LEN_VETOR);
    return 0;
}
```

O erro que recebo ao tentar compilar:

> error: lvalue required as decrement operand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você usa a macro assim

```
  PRINTARRAY(vetor, LEN_VETOR);
```

esta linha é substituida por

```
while (LEN_VETOR > 0) {
  printf("%d",vetor[LEN_VETOR]);
  LEN_VETOR--;
}
```

Estas linhas por sua vez são substituídas por

```
while (4 > 0) {
  printf("%d",vetor[4]);
  4--; /* ****** PROBLEMA */
}
```

por causa do define

```
#define LEN_VETOR 4
```

Só que "4--" é um comando inválido, porque está tentando modificar o valor de uma constante!
A solução ? Usar a macro com uma variável em lugar da constante, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PRINTARRAY(vetor,length) while (length > 0) { \
  printf("%d",vetor[length-1]); /* atencao aqui para o -1 */ \
  length--; \
  }

int main(void)
{
  int vetor[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  int lenVetor = LEN_VETOR.
  PRINTARRAY(vetor, lenVetor);
  return 0;
}
```